# Apache beam 2.34.0 SQSIO illegal mutation exception

Tags: java, apache-beam, amazon-sqs, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to read from sqs queue in batch mode and write to a local file using Apache beam 2.34.0 and AWS beam SDK v1 which throws Illegal mutation exception.

```
public class SqsReader {

    public void run(String[] args) {

        SqsReaderOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().
                as(SqsReaderOptions.class);
        Pipeline p = this.getPipeline(args);

        p.apply(SqsIO.read().withQueueUrl(options.getSourceQueueUrl())
                        .withMaxNumRecords(options.getNumberOfRecords()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new SqsMessageToJson()))
                .apply(TextIO.write()
                        .to(options.getLocalOutputLocation())
                        .withNumShards(options.getNumShards()));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new SqsReader().run(args);
    }

    public static class SqsMessageToJson extends DoFn<Message, String> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String message = Objects.requireNonNull(c.element()).getBody();
            c.output(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
Jan 10, 2022 11:37:05 AM org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector verifyUnmodifiedThrowingCheckedExceptions
WARNING: Coder of type class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder has a #structuralValue method which does not return true when the encoding of the elements is equal. Element Shard{source=org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.sqs.SqsUnboundedSource@5f19451c, maxNumRecords=1, maxReadTime=null}
Coder of type class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder has a #structuralValue method which does not return true when the encoding of the elements is equal. Element Shard{source=org.apache.beam.sdk.io.aws.sqs.SqsUnboundedSource@5f19451c, maxNumRecords=1, maxReadTime=null}

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.sdk.util.IllegalMutationException: PTransform SqsIO.Read/Read(SqsUnboundedSource)/Read/ParMultiDo(Read) mutated value ValueWithRecordId{id=[98, 55, 50, 51, 56, 51, 102, 57, 45, 97, 52, 100, 56, 45, 52, 99, 100, 50, 45, 97, 49, 55, 49, 45, 48, 57, 100, 48, 100, 53, 50, 51, 99, 50, 54, 51], value={MessageId: b72383f9-a4d8-4cd2-a171-09d0d523c263,ReceiptHandle: AQEBj2FXnTVQ==,MD5OfBody: 38db8cbd101e4c1cfbf47e31c2aaab75,Body: {"test-key": "test-value"},Attributes: {SentTimestamp=1641794775474},MessageAttributes: {requestTimeMsSinceEpoch={StringValue: 1641794824800,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],}}}} after it was output (new value was ValueWithRecordId{id=[98, 55, 50, 51, 56, 51, 102, 57, 45, 97, 52, 100, 56, 45, 52, 99, 100, 50, 45, 97, 49, 55, 49, 45, 48, 57, 100, 48, 100, 53, 50, 51, 99, 50, 54, 51], value={MessageId: b72383f9-a4d8-4cd2-a171-09d0d523c263,ReceiptHandle: DeVRF8vQATm1f+rHIvR3eaejlRHksL1R7WE4zDT7lSwdIs9gJCYKXFXnTVQ==,MD5OfBody: 38db8cbd101e4c1cfbf47e31c2aaab75,Body: {"test-key": "test-value"},Attributes: {SentTimestamp=1641794775474},MessageAttributes: {requestTimeMsSinceEpoch={StringValue: 1641794824800,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],}}}}). Values must not be mutated in any way after being output.
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.commit(ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:137)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.EvaluationContext.commitBundles(EvaluationContext.java:231)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.EvaluationContext.handleResult(EvaluationContext.java:163)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.QuiescenceDriver$TimerIterableCompletionCallback.handleResult(QuiescenceDriver.java:292)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.finishBundle(DirectTransformExecutor.java:194)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.IllegalMutationException: Value ValueWithRecordId{id=[98, 55, 50, 51, 56, 51, 102, 57, 45, 97, 52, 100, 56, 45, 52, 99, 100, 50, 45, 97, 49, 55, 49, 45, 48, 57, 100, 48, 100, 53, 50, 51, 99, 50, 54, 51], value={MessageId: b72383f9-a4d8-4cd2-a171-09d0d523c263,ReceiptHandle: AQEBj2KQ==,MD5OfBody: 38db8cbd101e4c1cfbf47e31c2aaab75,Body: {"test-key": "test-value"},Attributes: {SentTimestamp=1641794775474},MessageAttributes: {requestTimeMsSinceEpoch={StringValue: 1641794824800,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],}}}} mutated illegally, new value was ValueWithRecordId{id=[98, 55, 50, 51, 56, 51, 102, 57, 45, 97, 52, 100, 56, 45, 52, 99, 100, 50, 45, 97, 49, 55, 49, 45, 48, 57, 100, 48, 100, 53, 50, 51, 99, 50, 54, 51], value={MessageId: b72383f9-a4d8-4cd2-a171-09d0d523c263,ReceiptHandle: AQ==,MD5OfBody: 38db8cbd101e4c1cfbf47e31c2aaab75,Body: {"test-key": "test-value"},Attributes: {SentTimestamp=1641794775474},MessageAttributes: {requestTimeMsSinceEpoch={StringValue: 1641794824800,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],}}}}. Encoding was rO.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.illegalMutation(MutationDetectors.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.verifyUnmodifiedThrowingCheckedExceptions(MutationDetectors.java:153)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.verifyUnmodified(MutationDetectors.java:128)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.commit(ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:127)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.IllegalMutationException: Value ValueWithRecordId{id=[98, 55, 50, 51, 56, 51, 102, 57, 45, 97, 52, 100, 56, 45, 52, 99, 100, 50, 45, 97, 49, 55, 49, 45, 48, 57, 100, 48, 100, 53, 50, 51, 99, 50, 54, 51], value={MessageId: b72383f9-a4d8-4cd2-a171-09d0d523c263,ReceiptHandle: AQEBj=,MD5OfBody: 38db8cbd101e4c1cfbf47e31c2aaab75,Body: {"test-key": "test-value"},Attributes: {SentTimestamp=1641794775474},MessageAttributes: {requestTimeMsSinceEpoch={StringValue: 1641794824800,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],}}}} mutated illegally, new value was ValueWithRecordId{id=[98, 55, 50, 51, 56, 51, 102, 57, 45, 97, 52, 100, 56, 45, 52, 99, 100, 50, 45, 97, 49, 55, 49, 45, 48, 57, 100, 48, 100, 53, 50, 51, 99, 50, 54, 51], value={MessageId: b72383f9-a4d8-4cd2-a171-09d0d523c263,ReceiptHandle: AQE==,MD5OfBody: 38db8cbd101e4c1cfbf47e31c2aaab75,Body: {"test-key": "test-value"},Attributes: {SentTimestamp=1641794775474},MessageAttributes: {requestTimeMsSinceEpoch={StringValue: 1641794824800,StringListValues: [],BinaryListValues: [],}}}}. Encoding was rO2Mw.
```

where as the same code **works in apache beam 2.31.0** without any issues. What am I missing here?

Comment: Which version of the Beam AWS module are you using? Is this on AWS SDK v1 or v2?

Comment: @Moritz We are using AWS SDK v1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by an **indeterministic coder** (`SerializableCoder.of(Message.class)`) in combination with using the SQS reader in **batch mode**. Batch mode is implemented using `BoundedReadFromUnboundedSource`, which is known to cause issues. Usage of it is rather [discouraged](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2307).

You can follow [BEAM-13631](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13631) to follow progress on fixing the SQS message coder.

Currently I can't tell you what changes between 2.31 and 2.34 are triggering the issue. But possibly it might not be changes in the SQS IO itself. I'll keep investigating a bit further and hope to give an update on that later.

For now, I recommend trying a few things:

- First, try avoid using batch mode (so neither setting `maxNumRecords` nor `maxReadTime`). I'm pretty confident that this fixes your issue.
- Since recent versions of Beam, there's a separate module for AWS SDK v2 `beam-sdks-java-io-amazon-web-services2` (hence my question above). It uses a custom message class for transfer rather than the AWS SDK one and encoding should be deterministic. However, I noticed a few other bugs on the SDK v2 IOs when starting to look into it recently: [retry on invalid receipt handles](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13510), [SQS clients closed too early](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13509).

Please let me know if either one helps.

Comment: For our use case we want to run the pipeline as batch mode since frequency of the messages is minimal and it would become quite costly if we run in stream mode. I will try with option 2 and update the outcome.

Comment: I have tried using the aws sdk v2 and its working, But the SqsMessage class getters which have package private access which is impossible to access outside beam package. created a PR https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13638 for the same.

Comment: Bummer @BalasubramanianNaagarajan, haven't noticed before. I'll fix that quickly!

Comment: I was working on this Issue, but you have raised a PR.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware, the ticket was unassigned ... If you have a PR ready, feel free to share it on the ticket and I'll review! Generally, make sure to assign tickets to yourself if you plan working on them. If you don't have permissions to do so, please introduce yourself to dev@beam.apache.org and ask to be added as a contributor in the Beam issue tracker. Also, I'd recommend reading https://beam.apache.org/contribute/

Comment: Np. Your pull request Looks good. We can go ahead with that. Thanks. I will read the contrib guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O is much more complicated in Beam 2.34.0 than 2.31.0. For Beam 2.34.0, the [deleteBatch](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/sqs/SqsUnboundedReader.java#L584) logic **filters** messages **to delete** based on the **inflight** state. However, there are assumptions in the [extend](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/sqs/SqsUnboundedReader.java#L756) logic where the inflight state is modified to **exclude** messages that are **assumed expired or to be expired**. These messages are **not** explicitly requested by the I/O to be deleted from sqs nor dropped by the I/O itself (the I/O could be [processing](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/sqs/SqsUnboundedReader.java#L509) a message that should have been expired to wait for it to be resent).

Filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13627.

Though I'm not sure if pulling the same message again with a new receipt handle within the same bundle would cause the problem of mutation detection because receipt handle is part of the Message hashcode unless there is a hash collision in the mutation detector.

**TL;DR: debugging process**

The mutation was detected in the SqsUnboundedSource, not caused by any other code in the pipeline.

The code that reports the warning and throws the exception is [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/util/MutationDetectors.java#L145).

The only field changed is the Receipt handle. It's documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html) that:

> If you receive a message more than once, each time you receive it, you get a different receipt handle. You must provide the most recently received receipt handle when you request to delete the message (otherwise, the message might not be deleted).

There is no [aws_java_sdk_version](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/apache/beam/gradle/BeamModulePlugin.groovy#L447) change between Beam 2.31.0 and Beam 2.34.0. So AWS SDK shouldn't be the culprit.

There is a significant change between Beam 2.31.0 and Beam 2.34.0 for [SqsUnboundedReader](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/sqs/SqsUnboundedReader.java).

To receive a message more than once, the message must not have been deleted since the first time received. The deletion logic is invoked in [SqsCheckpointMark](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.34.0/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/sqs/SqsCheckpointMark.java).

Comment: Is there any work around available till the issue is fixed?

Comment: You may use the older SDK for now. And follow up in the JIRA ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-13627 to see further resolutions.